# how to make my android app sign in by facebook and get friends list like foursquare

Tags: java, android, facebook, social-networking, foursquare

i working on android app and i need it to sign in by facebook and get the user friends list to invite them to use the app and publish on there timeline LIKE Foursquare

any stable method ?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Or are you waiting for someone to do the work for you?

Comment: You are mixing different use-cases here. Such a functionality will be more kind of a 'service' since it is really specific to your needs. I think you will need to combine different frameworks/solutions to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Just read this, it has everything you need to know